# SQLite enforce immediate update

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I have problem regarding to enforcing immediate transaction commitment, I tried to insert 300 rows with a new transaction in each passing command, however after finishing inserting the 300 rows and calling commit command, I try to read the inserted rows and I get the result of nothing, however if I just called 'exit sub' I find all 300 records are written.

My question how to enforce transaction to commit all changes to database before calling another select command.

Comment: Transactions *do* commit. There is some error in your code.

Comment: No there is nothing with my code as when I break it as mentioned above, the transaction does commit.

Comment: If possible can you show your code?

Comment: I figure it out, I had a nesting transactions which was causing delay in transaction commitment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out, I had a nested transactions which was causing delay in transaction commitment